# PHP soap and namespaces. PHP Fatal error: Class 'Jira\SoapClient' not found

Tags: php, apache, soap, ubuntu

We are updating our codebase to use the namespace functionality provided in PHP-5.3+

Previously, our files all lived happily on the webserver in /htdocs/php but now we are separating our scripts, and putting our PHP libraries in /htdocs/php/lib/

In /htdocs/php/lib/ we have a file called Jira.php which we have given a namespace to:

```
<?php
# Define a namespace for this library
namespace Jira;

function create_client($jira_url, $options)
{
    global $client;

    try
    {
            $client = new SoapClient($jira_url, $options);
    }
    catch (Exception $error)
    {
            echo $error -> getMessage() . "<br/><p style='color:red'> Could not connect to Jira </p>";
    }
}
?>
```

However, when we try and call this function from a script in /htdocs/php, we are getting the class not found error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Jira\SoapClient' not found
```

This is failing when we try creating the SoapClient object.

I have verified that I have the php-soap package installed in /usr/share/php/SOAP/
and php_info(); is showing that it is enabled etc.

So presumably this is a problem with the namespace convention. How do we include that class without it throwing an error?

Regards,
**ns**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SoapClient is probably assigned to the global namespace.

In your script the current namespace is `Jira.`

Try using:

```
$client = new \SoapClient($jira_url, $options);
```

Comment: Forgot to add, the \ before SoapClient means the globla namespace. So, if you have another class in the `modules` namespace, use `\modules\myclass` to reference it. You should also look into the use statement (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) as well.